# VS2013 git: Can't Publish Branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am running into a problem trying to publish a branch to a private remote git server in VS 2013. I believe it's because I haven't specified the userid/password credentials for the remote server (I don't recall being asked for any when I first pointed Visual Studio at the remote server).

How do I go about supplying the needed credentials?

Also, how would I go about publishing to a different remote repository? Once a remote is configured there doesn't seem to be a way from within Visual Studio to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. Turns out I left off the ".git" from the remote repository URL when I originally tried publishing the master branch to it.

Fixing that problem required modifying the config file, located in the root of the local respository. It's just a plain text file which you can edit with VS.